# Prevent UWP apps from opening

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, uwp

I am trying to prevent some apps and processes from opening.
When I want to prevent a desktop app or a process from opening, I am hooking the `CreateProcess` function and opening only if the particular app/proc is allowed to run.

For instance, if the user tries to open notepad, my program would first check if notepad is allowed to run in the system, and only if it is allowed, notepad is opened. This is working perfectly for normal applications and procs.

But this method doesn't seem to work with UWP applications like Groove Music for example.

When I use this method, the method to check if the application is allowed to run has to be executed only after the application opens.

I want my program to do the same for UWP apps also. If the User tries to open Groove music, I want my program to check if it is allowed to run, and only if is is, the application should open.

Is there any way to prevent a specific UWP application from opening in the first place if it is not whitelisted, as in, is there any method to hook the `ActivateApplication` method to check and then open the application?

Comment: If this question is not properly framed or if it does not properly explain the problem, please do lemme know

Comment: Have you looked at AppLocker?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT, I didn't want to go there. I have been going through the basics of Windows SDK and I just wanted to learn to implement it programmatically.